# Align some parts, some other parts, then all parts of the lines

Tags: align

The following is what I need: I want (1) and (2) aligned, the first three equal signs aligned, the next three equal signs aligned, and all the left parentheses aligned.

```
(1) x=1+2+3           (by the problem condition)
     =3+3             (by sum law)
     =6               (same as above)
(2) x+y=(3+4)+(5+6)   (by the condition)
       =7+11          (by sum law)
       =18            (the final result)
```

I tried to use align but it gives different output (I know it doesn't work). Can you help? Thanks.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    (1) x&=1+2+3          && (\text{by the problem condition})\\
         &=3+3            && (\text{by sum law})\\
         &=6              && (\text{same as above})\\
    (2) x+y&=(3+4)+(5+6)  && (\text{by the condition})\\
           &=7+11         && (\text{by sum law})\\
           &=18           && (\text{the final result})
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understood your formatting objective as follows: (i) you do *not* want the equal symbols in the first group of three lines to be aligned with the equal symbols in the second group of three lines; and (ii) you do want the equal symbols to be aligned *within* each group of three lines.

If this interpretation is correct, the following code achieves what you're looking for.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  (1)&\quad 
  \begin{aligned}[t]
     x&=1+2+3  \\
      &=3+3 \\
      &= 6
  \end{aligned}
  &\qquad &
  \begin{aligned}[t]         
      &(\text{by the problem condition})\\
      &(\text{by sum law})\\
      &(\text{same as above})
  \end{aligned} \\[\jot]
  (2)&\quad
   \begin{aligned}[t]
     x+y&=(3+4)+(5+6) \\
        &=7+11        \\
        &=18
   \end{aligned}
   & &
   \begin{aligned}[t]
      &(\text{by the condition})\\
      &(\text{by sum law})\\
      &(\text{the final result})
   \end{aligned}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

What we can do at TeX primitive level:

```
\def\hb#1{\hbox{(#1)}}
\halign{\hss#\unskip\quad\hss&\vtop{#}&\quad\vtop{#}\cr
   (1) & \halign{$\hfil#$&${}#\hfil$\cr
            x &= 1 + 2 + 3 \cr
              &= 3 + 3 \cr
              &= 6 \cr
         } &                  \hb{by the problem condition}
                              \hb{by sum law}
                              \hb{same as above} 
   \cr \noalign{\medskip}
   (2) & \halign{$\hfil#$&${}#\hfil$\cr
            x+y &= (3+4)+(5+6) \cr
                &= 7+11 \cr
                &= 18 \cr
         } &                  \hb{by the condition}
                              \hb{by sum law}
                              \hb{the final result} \cr
}  
\bye
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this effect?
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
    & (1) & x   &=1+2+3          && (\text{by the problem condition})\\
    &&          &=3+3            && (\text{by sum law})\\
    &&          &=6              && (\text{same as above})\\
    & (2) &\ x+y&=(3+4)+(5+6)    &\quad& (\text{by the condition})\\
    &&          &=7+11           && (\text{by sum law})\\
    &&          &=18             && (\text{the final result})
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. The equal signs are not to be all aligned. Mico got it correctly. Thanks anyway!